# Eclipse auto refresh resources

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any other setting to stop Eclipse auto-refresh? I have disabled everything related to refresh at

> General - Workspace - Refresh Automatically

. However, it still refresh resources on every SVN check-in or when I load eclipse. This is killing me :/

Comment: it refreshes resources when you load eclipse ? i'm curious to know when that could be a bad thing

Comment: I wish Eclipse auto-saved like Intellij :(

Comment: I am maintaining a project (developed by someone else). All the data (in GBs) is in the workspace. Thus, on load it starts refreshing those contents as well. I can't move them anywhere else and can't exclude those folders from auto refresh.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you import project from SVN and choose copy in to workspace? so when you want SVN update, copy those source file in to workspace.

PS: I import project from SVN and didn't copy in to workspace. what I do is i manually update SVN to get lasted code. if I don't want lasted code, I don't update SVN.